# Antlr4 freeze after upgrade from 4.1 to 4.3

Tags: antlr4

I made a grammar in antlr 4.1.

I tried to upgrade to 4.5.1, but freezes.
I tested with 4.2 and works well. Then I tried the 4.3 and the freezing began to occur.

When I generated the parser and lexer is not displayed error or warning.

Apparently it's frozen in ParserATNSimulator.closure

Something has changed in version 4.3 and higher?

Thanks a Lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you generate your parser class after upgrading ANTLR ? I just upgraded to 4.5.1 trouble-free.

Version 4.3 seems to be compatible with previous versions. However version 4.2.2 have some issues apparently: see the 'Breaking changes' section of the [v4.2.2 release notes](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/releases/tag/4.2.2).

Comment: v4.3 does have breaking changes although it does not mention the ParserATNSimulator.

Comment: The problem is at version 4.2.2, thank you.
In 'Breaking changes' section
"The signature of the Following methods changed to support the proper handling of grammars with multiple explicit references to EOF. These methods are rarely, if ever, overridden in client applications."
My grammar has several references to the EOF.
I will try to refactor it to avoid having to have several references to EOF, and try to isolate the problem to open an issue.

Thanks a lot.